# Как менять значение переменной в js в зависимости от ширины окна?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Переменная является числом, которое задает количество выводимых иконок. На разных шириных экрана оно должно быть разным. Как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 7):

Можно использовать [CSS Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) через функцию 
 [matchMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia)

```js
const mq = window.matchMedia('(max-width: 570px)')

if (mq.matches) {
    // ширина окна меньше, чем 570px
    alert('Меньше')
} else {
    // ширина окна больше, чем 570px
    alert('Больше')
}
```

Вы также можете добавить прослушиватель событий, который срабатывает при обнаружении изменения:

```js
// обработчик события медиа-запроса
const mq = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 500px)")

mq.addListener(WidthChange)
WidthChange(mq)

// изменение медиа-запроса
function WidthChange(mq) {
  if (mq.matches) {
    // ширина окна не менее 500px
    alert('Больше')
  } else {
    // ширина окна меньше 500px
    alert('Меньше')
  }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]